# Loading data and pictures causes error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to load all faculty if students course is BSIT then load all BSIT faculties to the picture box

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim arrImage() As Byte
Dim myMS As New IO.MemoryStream
Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
Try
  sSQL = "SELECT b.FacultyID, b.Image, b.Course, a.Course"
  sSQL = sSQL & " FROM studentsrecords as a left join facultynew as b "
  sSQL = sSQL & " on a.ID = b.FacultyID WHERE(a.Course = @Course) order by a.Course"

  con = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
  con.Open()
  cmd.Connection = con
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  cmd.CommandText = sSQL
  '  cmd.Parameters.Add("@EvaluationID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value

  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
  If dr.HasRows Then
    While dr.Read
      If Not IsDBNull(dr("Image")) Then
        myMS = New IO.MemoryStream
        arrImage = dr("Image")
        For Each ar As Byte In arrImage
          myMS.WriteByte(ar)
        Next
      End If
      Select Case dr("Course")
        Case 1
          Me.pic1.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 2
          Me.pic2.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 3
          Me.pic3.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic3.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 4
          Me.pic4.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic4.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 5
          Me.pic5.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic5.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 6
          Me.pic6.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic6.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 7
          Me.pic7.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic7.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 8
          Me.pic8.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic8.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 9
          Me.pic9.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic9.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
        Case 10
          Me.pic10.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
          Me.pic10.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMS)
      End Select
    End While
  End If

  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ErrorToString)
  Finally
    con.Close()
  End Try
```

Comment: which line cause error? and what error?

Comment: actually i uncomment cmd.parameters.blah blah

i replace evaluationID to Course stil it says 
property acess must assign to the property or use its value

Comment: You probably need to edit your question and include more about the error you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvaluationID", ValueForParameter)
```

This for pic

```
Dim bm As Bitmap
arrImage() = dr.Item("Picture")
ms.Write(arrImage, 78, arrImage.Length - 78)
bm = New Bitmap(ms)

Select Case dr("Course")
    Case 1
      Me.pic1.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
      Me.pic1.Image = bm
```

Comment: i am a newbie sir.,.,

`code`Dim bm As Bitmap
arrImage() = dr.Item("Picture")
ms.Write(arrImage, 78, arrImage.Length - 78)
bm = New Bitmap(ms)
Me.pic1.Image = bm

where in the project should i put it?